# After removing lines from chart, I can't append new lines (d3 line chart)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently, I have a leaflet map and a D3 chart where I can select a point and get associated data for a line chart. I can add as many lines as I want to the line chart. To remove, I created a html button where on click I can remove all path lines. The issue I'm having is that once this button is clicked and the lines are gone, I can't append more. Does anyone know how to solve this? Here's the code:

```
<div class= "timeline">
    <svg width="100%">
        <g id="lines"></g>
        <g id= "legend"></g>
    </svg>


function setUp(){
  var div = d3.select(".timeline");
  var svg = div.select("svg") //sets size of svgContainer

  x.range([0, width]);
  y.range([height, 0]);

  svg.attr("width", timelineBounds.width)
  .attr("height", timelineBounds.height);

  svg.append("rect") //sets svg rect in container
  //.style("stroke", "black")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .attr("width", 900)
  .attr("height", 150);

 var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(9);
 var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(7);

 svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top +   height) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

svg.append("text")      // text label for the x axis
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom + 15) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Time");

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
.call(yAxis);

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("PM 2.5 %");
}
```

This is where I actually draw the lines:

```
function drawChart (){
  var svg = d3.select("div svg"); 

 // Scale the range of the data
 var valueline = d3.line()
 .x(function (d) {
 return x(d.time);
})
.y(function (d) {
  return y(d.pm25);
})

 // adds the svg attributes to container
   let lines = svg.select('#lines').selectAll('path').data(lineArray,      function (d) {
  return d.id;
}); //any path in svg is selected then assigns the data from the array
lines.exit().remove(); //remove any paths that have been removed from   the array that no longer associated data
let linesEnter = lines.enter().append("path"); // looks at data not associated with path and then pairs it
lines = linesEnter.merge(lines); //combines new path/data pairs with previous, unremoved data

lines.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
.attr("d", d => { return valueline(d.sensorData); })
.attr("class", "line-style")
.attr("stroke", d => lineColor(d.id));
```

Here is the function that is called when the button is clicked:

```
function clearData(){
  d3.selectAll("#lines").remove();
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What element has `lines` as ID? And why are you using `selectAll` since IDs are unique?

Comment: I have a g element named lines that I use to group the SVG lines together. There's probably a better way to do that, but this is how I chose to do it.

Comment: So, you have your answer: you are removing the `<g>` element but you are never re-appending it.

Comment: Yes. What would be the best way to fix that?

Comment: Re-append the element. However, I'd advise you to search how to update a D3 chart without removing and re-appending elements, which I call a "lazy approach".

Comment: Okay, yes. Sorry, I'm not explaining my problem well. I can't just do this: d3.select("svg").append("#lines"). You're totally right about the issue of removing and not re-appending, so if I change it to instead remove the path: d3.selectAll("path").remove(); (which sounds like it is a better choice from your initial question) it does what I want, but also removes the x-axis line and when I click to add another point, it simply shows the old data as well. Do I also need to re-append the x-axis or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Re-append the **group** element.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into updating it like you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
function clearData(){
  lineArray = []; 
  d3.selectAll("#lines").html('');  
}
```